# How to get global mouse position in Qt6?

Tags: c++, windows, qt6

I'm trying to get global position of the mouse however the functions mentioned in older topics are either deprecated or not working as intended. I have tried `QCursor::pos()` as seen below but it didn't work as intended.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QCursor>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << QCursor::pos().x() << " " << QCursor::pos().y() << std::endl;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output: 2147483647 2147483647

Comment: Please show your code and clarify what you mean by `"it didn't work as intended"`.

Comment: @G.M. I have added the code and the output, it is clear now.

Comment: Try changing `QCoreApplication` to `QGuiApplication`.  Also note that `a.exec()` is redundant in this case -- it's never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple. `QCursor` is in the Gui module of Qt see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcursor.html), so you have to change `QCoreApplication` to `QGuiApplication` and then it works (already tested it).